# How do I make the code easier for the phone?

Tags: android

I am trying to record audio.  Unfortunately the code is so dense that the phone skips samples when it is recording.  Does anyone have any advice on how to simplify the code and make it easier on the processor?  A point where I was hoping to get help was to reduce the for loop to something simpler.

```
recordingThread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

                try {
                    file.createNewFile();

                    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
                    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

                    short[] audioData = new short[bufferSize];

                    audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                            RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING,
                            bufferSize);

                    audioRecord.startRecording();

                    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            writeAudioDataToFile();
                        }
                    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

                    recordingThread.start();

                    while (!recordbuttonstatus) {
                        int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, bufferSize);

                        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++) {
                            dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
                        }
                    }

                    dataOutputStream.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
                recordingThread2.start();
```

Comment: Why arent you using the [framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) developed to do that work optimally?

Comment: What issue are you observing? There's no way your phone can skip the instructions.

Comment: First: Use the framework as suggested, it's a lot faster than anything you can do in java. And as for the most likely performance problem: You are writing one single `short` sample at a time ... why the `DataOutputStream`?

Comment: Egor I am recording my voice into a WAV file (the code for that is not included here) and a pcm file (the code for that is included here).  The WAV file and the pcm file are made successfully but the audio plays back sped up because the recorder skipped samples.  I read in another question from someone who had the same issue that it is because the thread demanded too much.

Comment: I am also not using framework because I am using audioRecord and audioTrack to record and play back the pcm fie.

Comment: Seem's that you're writing to the disk in the same thread that you're using to record the audio (`dataOutputStream.writeShort()`). That will most likely block and hence you're losing samples. Put the data into a non blocking thread-safe queue and read it from there on another thread that saves everything to disk.